# Why doesn't "$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{0}=\infty$" prove division by zero is possible?

Tags: limits

A friend of mine asked me one day: is a possible division by zero? - I answer you that, division by zero is not possible, the said ok, I want to solve this this example
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x-1}
$$

I did not think much and said that the result is $\infty$, because

$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{1-1}=\frac{1}{0}=\infty
$$

He then asked, amazed, as in this case are then division by zero is possible, therefore, $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x-1}=\infty$, when the first bit of thae that division by zero is not possible.

My question is: is my answer correct, that is a $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{x-1}=\infty$, and how is it possible then that division by zero is not possible.

Please help to clarify this example.

Previously, thank you for your answers.

Comment: HINT: $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{1}{x-1}=-\infty$$

Comment: We are talking about operations on the real numbers, but this logic here is kind of like computing that $\frac{1}{0}=$grapefruit means that division by zero is possible. What's that you ask? Grapefruit isn't a (real) number? *Neither is $\infty$* There are some systems that incorporate operations with $\infty$, but in the most common systems, there are algebraic barriers to allowing $0$ to have an inverse. That aside, it doesn't make sense to call the limit  $\infty$ either because when approaching from the left, the limit is $-\infty$

Answer (score 6):

The reason that the existence of the limit above doesn't imply that division by $0$ is possible is simply because
$$\textbf{taking the limit} \ne \textbf{actually dividing}$$

Division by $0$ is ambiguous, *unless defined* otherwise.  (I believe there are some instances in which mathematicians do define it, but these are few and far between.)

---

**A side note:**
The example limit you have doesn't actually tend to $\infty$, rather it does not exist (the left- and right-hand limits are not the same).

An example that demonstrates what you want is:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\to \infty$$

Comment: thanks and your answer sir

Comment: @MatemaTika No problem!  I'm glad to help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Division by zero is not possible. What number could $1/0$ be? If $1/0=x$ where $x$ is a real number and we want the ususal arithmetic rules to hold we sloud have $1=0\cdot x=0$, which clearly is not the case.

Then, why do we say sometimes that $1/0=\infty$? This is just a shortcut fort the following:

> If a certain quantity approaching $1$ is divided by another quantity
>   approaching $0$, then the quotient can be made larger than any
>   preassigned number.

*Note*: I am not dealing here with the fact that the quotient can be very large and positive or very large in absolute value and negative.

It is in this sense that we say that
$$
\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{1}{x-1}=+\infty.
$$
The quantity $1/(x-1)$ can be made larger than any preassigned number by taking $x$ sufficiently close to (and larger than) $1$.

Comment: thank you vary much for your answer sir