Analysis of the division by zero
So, we know that the result $\frac{1}{n}$ gets bigger on the positive side when n (positive) gets closer to zero, and that the result also gets bigger on the negative side when n (negative) gets closer to zero. Therefore, $\frac{1}{0}=\pm\infty.$ We also know that $\frac{k}{n}$ results in $k⋅\frac{1}{n}$. Therefore,$$\frac{n}{0}=n⋅\frac{1}{0}=n⋅\pm\infty$$
It also seems that $-n$ also outputs the same result.
What do you think of my analysis? Is there any flaws that I have missed? If there are any flaws, do tell me in the comment section below.

Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457365/why-doesnt-lim-x-to-1-frac1x-1-frac10-infty-prove-division-by?noredirect=1

And https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125186/42969

Everything you wrote before the "therefore" is true, but your final equation doesn't really make sense. What does "$n\cdot\pm\infty$" mean? If you're proposing a number system that includes infinities and division by zero, there are many questions to be answered. (Like what is $\infty-\infty$?)

@Karl Any number minus itself is always zero.

Are you also suggesting $\frac{1}{0} =  \pm \infty  \Rightarrow 1 = 0 \cdot  \pm \infty$?
